# Html and Css issue with navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am very new to html and css but i am having an issue with my navigation bar and the hamburger menu the li a elements are going behind my images and i cannot seem to fix this issue. If you can also look at the first image you will see the li a elements and the crimson color background that is mean't to be on top.

```css
nav {
  height: 80px;
  background: crimson;
  opacity: 80%;
}
nav h1 {
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 12%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}
nav ul {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin: 0 15px;
}
nav ul li a {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav ul li a:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: right;
  transition: transform 0.4s linear;
}
nav ul li a:hover:before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: left;
}
label #btn,
label #cancel {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  float: right;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
#check {
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 1118px) {
  nav h1 {
    left: 8%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 944px) {
  nav h1 {
    left: 6%;
    top: 20px;
    width: 300px;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    font-size: 17px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 860px) {
  label #btn {
    display: block;
  }
  ul {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: crimson;
    top: 80px;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    margin: 50px;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <label for="check">
        <i class="fas fa-bars" id="btn"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-times" id="cancel"></i>
    </label>
    <h1>Benji's Equestrian</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The above is the current css for the navigation bar and below i will post the html.

```
<nav>
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
<label for="check">
    <i class="fas fa-bars" id="btn"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-times" id="cancel"></i>
</label>
<h1>Benji's Equestrian</h1>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

**The issue with the navigation bar and elements:**

[image]

**The Navigation bar**

[image]

```css
@media (max-width: 860px) {
  label #btn {
    display: block;
  }
  ul {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: crimson;
    top: 80px;
    left: -100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.5s;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    margin: 50px;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  #check:checked ~ ul {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

The above css is where i think the issue is, i have tried adding z-index:100; to the .nav element and it doesn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If menu elements have to be top of your image, you have to use `z-index`. Just add `z-index` and declare it like 100 or 1000. Don't for get to add any `position` (relative, absolute etc.) value to element.

```
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 80px;
    margin: 0 15px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.

Comment: Hello, I think it is something to do with this code. Because when i remove this code the Hamburger menu gets removed. but the above wont solve the issue.

@media (max-width: 860px) {
  label #btn {
    display: block;
  }
  ul {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: crimson;
    top: 80px;
    left: -100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.5s;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    margin: 50px;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  #check:checked ~ ul {
    left: 0;
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make sure your `nav` on top of everything, then just add `z-index` to any amount greater than `0` or like how usually people do `100` and maybe even `1000`:-

```
nav {
  height: 80px;
  background: crimson;
  opacity: 80%;
  z-index: 100
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.